# Show that $f$ is differentiable in $0$(multidimensional)

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $ 0 \in \Omega$. Let be $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $|f(x)| \le |x|^{a}$ for some $a > 1$ and all $a \in \Omega$. Show that f is totally differentiable in $0$.

I don't know how could I prove it to a multidimensional case, may I can use the Jacobian matrix to show this property? I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: You probably mean "for some $a>1$ and all $x\in\Omega$" (and it's usually a good idea to put quantifiers at the front of a sentence).. Regarding how to show this, first write down the definition of $f$ being differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that the hypotesis implies that $f(0)=0$. By definition, we say that $f$ (multivariable) is differentiable at $a$ if there is a linear transformation $T$ such that the following limit exists

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{||f(x)-f(x)-T(x-a)||}{||x-a||}$

Consider $T_0$ the null-transformation ($T_0(x)=0,\forall x$). By hypotesis

$\frac{||f(h)-f(0)-T_0(h-0)||}{||h||}=\frac{||f(h)||}{||h||}\leq \frac{||h||^a}{||h||}=||h||^{a-1}$.

Since $a>1$, taking the limit

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{||f(h)-f(0)-T_0(h-0)||}{||h||}\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}||h||^{a-1}=0$.

You can complete the details.